# Pushing a tag to private docker registry in artifactory fails from mac

Tags: macos, docker, artifactory, docker-registry

So, we have permissions setup on who can push to the docker registry in artifactory. Now, I created a dockercfg file in $HOME/.dockercfg on my mac and added the username and passing using the curl command:

```
curl -uaaaaa:bbbbbbb "https://docker.io/v2/auth" >> $HOME/.dockercfg
```

After that when I try to push an image to docker registry, it fails with the below error:

```
unauthorized: The client does not have permission to push to the repository.
```

When I look at the docker request.log in the registry, I see its trying to push as anonymous from my mac. This is very confusing. Even though I have the $HOME/.dockercfg which has a user.

I also tried the docker login docker.io way but that too isnt helping.

It seems that the artifactory docker registry isnt able to find the user info when I am pushing from my mac and shows as **anonymous**.

My artifactory server version is 4.5.0 and docker 1.12.0-rc2.

Can anybody please help.

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge Docker 1.12 no longer supports configuration placed under `~/.dockercfg` instead it should be placed under `~/.docker/config.json` --> In any case the method you're using was relevant for the older docker clients, you should use `docker login` to authenticate your docker client with Artifactory.

As a side note, Your version of Artifactory is a bit old - newer versions have made significant changes to support the newer Docker versions so you should upgrade before trying again.

Also remember to configure your [Reverse Proxy](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Configuring+a+Reverse+Proxy#ConfiguringaReverseProxy-DockerReverseProxySettings) to work with Artifactory and that you also probably need to set up Docker (and your reverse proxy) to use [self-signed certificates](https://docs.docker.com/registry/insecure/#/using-self-signed-certificates).

Comment: I have also tried docker login abc.com and that succeed's but the minute I try to push it fails with `unauthorized: The client does not have permission to push to the repository.` error. I will take a look at Reverse proxy.

Comment: You should also check permissions on that repo for that user, try and see in the `access.log` if the requests are coming in as anonymous or authenticated with the user you expect.

Comment: I can use that same user from my Linux box and it just works. Somehow mac isnt able to pass the user info or the artifactory version that I have doesnt suppose docker 1.10 and above.